# Can't access entity from within the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm passing `IList<Post>` to `View(posts)`.
`Post` is a `linqToSql` generated model class.
`Post` has an `FK` relation to the `Category` table by `Id`.

When I'm iterating over `IList<Post>` inside my `View` and trying to access `post.Category.Title` I'm receiving an error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.

How can I get `Category.Title` for each of my `Posts` right from `View`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, actually what the error tells you!  In other words, keep your DataContext open till you finished working with the data.

Previously I just create a DataContext per page request, and dispose it at the end of the request. Worked relatively well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me!
I've just forgot that I'm writing:
using (BlaBlaDataContext dataContext = new BlaBlaDataContext())
{ return bla-bla-bla; }

 :)